# Why doesn't `env GTK_THEME=Adwaita` work in .desktop files?

Tags: themes, gtk, app-shortcuts, desktop-environment

It'll be no shock that some non-elementary OS apps don't look right with the default elementary OS theme. I understand that theming is a Hard Problem™.

Sometimes buttons don't look like buttons, or half the buttons have bevels and the other half don't, or UI controls have white text on a grey background color, or sometimes the aesthetics are just bad.

[Seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse/), [MenuLibre](https://bluesabre.org/projects/menulibre), and [Remmina](https://bluesabre.org/projects/menulibre) are just a few examples.

[image: Screenshot of Seahorse (Passwords and Keys) showing default elementary OS theme]

However, you *can* specify a custom theme for a GTK app with [the `GTK_THEME` environment variable](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/running.html#environment-variables), and in many cases using the Adwaita theme fixes the display issues. Thus, this should be possible with a `.desktop` file, too; for example, `Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita seahorse`.

However, annoyingly, this modification doesn't work for certain applications. Seahorse is one. Running `env GTK_THEME=Adwaita seahorse` *from a terminal* however, has the expected effect.

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**: comment out the line that starts with `DBusActivatable` in the `.desktop` file.

[This section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_entries#Modify_environment_variables) of the always-reliable Arch wiki article for desktop entries was clutch:

> #### Modify command line arguments
>
> To change or add the command line arguments, edit the `Exec=` line to append the desired options. As an example, with the original line commented out:
>
> ```
> # ~/.local/share/applications/steam.desktop
> ...
> # Exec=/usr/bin/steam-runtime %U
> Exec=/usr/bin/steam-runtime -no-browser %U
> ...
> ```
>
> Also remove `DBusActivatable=true` (or set it to `false`) if present as it will cause the Exec line to be ignored.[[2](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/running.html#environment-variables)]

That "[2]" refers you to [this section](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/running.html#environment-variables) of the documentation on gtk.org, which elaborates:

> If `DBusActivatable` is `true` **and the desktop file name looks like a valid application ID**, then the `Exec` line will be ignored and your application will be started by way of D-Bus activation instead (using the name of the desktop file as the application ID). *(emphasis mine)*

The bolded part is key: the `.desktop` filename in this case is `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.seahorse.Application.desktop`, which, yep, looks like "a valid application ID." I don't know what all the DBus activation stuff is all about, but who cares. I fixed my problem.

Comment out that line with a `#` and problem solved. Yes, I do this as root, for reasons beyond the scope of this question, and yes, I'm OK with having to repeat that step if an update to the package ships a new `.desktop` file. Those are minor inconveniences.